# MediaController is not shown after onResume()

Tags: android

This is my activity for a video player:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity
         implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, 
                    MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {
....
}
```

and in its `onPause` method I don't release the `MediaPlayer` and I just `pause` it:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    lastPlaybackInfo.IsPlaying = mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    mMediaPlayer.pause();
    lastPlaybackInfo.SeekPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

and in `onResume`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            if (lastPlaybackInfo.IsPlaying) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            } else {
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(lastPlaybackInfo.SeekPosition);
            }
            mMediaController.show();
        }
}
```

and the onTouchEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            mMediaController.show();
            return true;
}
```

I have two problems:

1. The first problem is that the once the app is resumed, the `MediaController` which is tied to `MediaPlayer` is shown only one time (the call in `onResume`), and after that, the calls in `onTouchEvent` doesn't show `MediaController`.
2. The second one is that, if `MediaPlayer` was paused before app getting paused, after resuming the app, the `SurfaceView` tied to `MediaPlayer` is black and doesn't show the very last rendered frame.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I found out if we run the code inside `onResume` with a delay to let the layout refresh itself, both of the problems would get resolved.

Here's how:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        if (IsMediaReady && IsSubtitleReady) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (lastPlaybackInfo.IsPlaying) {
                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                        } else {
                            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(lastPlaybackInfo.SeekPosition);
                        }
                        mMediaController.show();
                    }
                }, 100);

            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception in resume");
    }
}
```